# Doing an embedded HTTP server with Comet

Tags: java, http, comet

I love the idea of Grizzly, but I can't find any good examples to work with.  Well, any good tutorial...  I want to have an embedded HTTP server that I can talk to from Dojo.  I don't want a J2EE server and I want to use Java.  What do you folks think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java6 has a simple embedded http server.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html

Comment: True, but Grizzly provides features that http server doesn't.

Comment: What feature do you need that is missing?

Comment: Sorry, that is my natural work reaction. I sometimes think no one knows HttpServer exists, so I like to point it out. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 3):

[StreamHub Push Server](http://www.stream-hub.com) is a Comet server written in Java.  you can use it as a JAR to embed it in your stack.  It also works as a simple HTTP server.  It's not integrated with dojo.io but there are plenty of good examples using a simple javascript library.

```
var hub = new StreamHub();
hub.connect("http://localhost:7979/");
hub.subscribe("MyTopic", function(topic, json) {
    alert("got update on topic: " + topic + " MyField=" + json['MyField']);
});
// ...
```

Oh, and for a good tutorial try [Getting Started with StreamHub and Comet](http://streamhub.blogspot.com/2009/07/getting-started-with-streamhub-and.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Jetty](http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty/) has support for asynch servlet continuations and comet-style programming. See the [documentation index](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Documentation). It can also be easily run embedded within another java application